# How to perform operation on specific bits in perl

Tags: perl, binary

Lets assume I have a hexadecimal value 0x78. I need to add 1 to first 4 bits ie 3:0 and add 2 to last 4 bits ie. [7:4]. Further when I add 1 to 0xF it should not roll over to the next value and should stay as 0xF. Same applies for subtraction. The approach I have tried so far is:

```
$byte=0x78;
$byte2 = unpack('b4', $byte);
print "byte2 = $byte2 \n";
```

--> Here the output is 1000 so I have tried to extract the first 4 bits, and similarly I can right shift and extract last 4 bits and perform the operation.
But to perform addition or subtraction, I wanted to convert 1000 back to hex format so that I can do 0x8 +/- 1. For that I tried:

```
$hex2 = sprintf('%02x', $byte2);
print "hex2 = $hex2 \n";
```

--> Output is 3e8. I do not understand why I get 3e8 instead of just 8 or 08, since it is supposed to print only 2 values in hex format.

In the above command when I manually enter 
$hex2 = sprintf('%02x', 0b1000); I get the correct result. So perl is taking it as a string rather than a numeric value. Is there some way I can convert that string to a binary number? Any other easier method or approach would be helpful.

Comment: `unpack 'bX'` takes a string of bytes, but you passed a number. You just got lucky you got the right answer, since you're actually getting the binary of `37 38` (the Unicode code points of `7` and `8`) when you want the binary of `78`.

Comment: Binary is a text representation of a number. You don't want to work in binary (text), you want to work with numbers. Use the bitwise operators with `$byte`.

Answer (score 1):

We can get each byte by ANDing and shifting:

```
$byte1 = $byte & 0xf;
$byte2 = ($byte & 0xf0) >> 4;
printf "byte1: 0x%x\n", $byte1;
printf "byte2: 0x%x\n", $byte2;

# prints
byte1: 0x8
byte2: 0x7
```

Addition/subtraction with special conditions you listed can be done on these bytes and the new value can be reconstructed with shifts and addition:

```
($byte1 < 0xf) ? ($byte1 += 1) : ($byte1 = 0xf);
($byte2 < 0xe) ? ($byte2 += 2) : ($byte2 = 0xf);
# or do subtraction stuff.

$new_val = ($byte2 << 4) + $byte1;
printf "new val: 0x%x\n", $new_val;

# prints
new val: 0x99
```

You're getting '3e8' because $byte2 is '1000', which, when translated into hex is '0x3e8'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off with something like:

```
sub byte_to_two_nibbles($) {
    my $byte = shift;
    return int($byte / 16), ($byte % 16);
}

sub two_nibbles_to_byte($$) {
    return $_[0] * 16 + $_[1];
}

my ($msn, $lsn) = byte_to_two_nibbles 0x78;
$msn += 1; $msn = 15 if $msn > 15;
$lsn += 2; $lsn = 15 if $lsn > 15;
my $result = two_nibbles_to_byte $msn, $lsn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [oct](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/oct.html) function:

```
$byte2 = oct("0b$byte2");
my $hex2 = sprintf('%02x', $byte2);
print "hex2 = $hex2 \n";
```

Prints:

```
hex2 = 08
```